# Is IntelliJ's support for Dockerized Python environments compatible with Python running on a Windows container?

Tags: docker, intellij-idea, pycharm, windows-container

My Python project is very windows-centric, we want the benefits of containers but we can't give up Windows just yet.

I'd like to be able to use the Dockerized remote python interpreter feature that comes with IntelliJ. This works flawlessly with Python running on a standard Linux container, but appears to work not at all for Python running on a Windows container.

I've built a new image based on a standard Microsoft Server core image. I've installed Miniconda, bootstrapped a Python environment and verified that I can start an interactive Python session from the command prompt.

Whenever I try to set this up I get an error message: "Can't retrieve image ID from build stream". This occurs at the moment when IntelliJ would have normally detected the python interpreter and it's installed libraries.

[image]

I also tried giving the full path for the interpreter: c:\miniconda\envs\htp\python.exe

I've never seen any mention that this works in the documentation, but nor have I seen any mention that it does not work. I totally accept that Windows Containers are an oddity, so it's entirely possible that IntelliJ's remote-Python feature was never tested on Python running in Windows containers.

So, has anybody got this feature working with Python running on a Windows container yet? Is there any reason to believe that it does or does not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regrettably, it is not supported yet. Please vote for the feature request https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-45222 in order to increase its priority.